# Currency - is a safety pilot a passenger per the regs (FAA)?

Tags: faa-regulations, currency

Per the regs in FAR 61.57, for a pilot trying to get current (for night or day) that is presently not current for carrying passengers, in a Cessna 172 where only one crew member is required, would a properly rated safety pilot sitting in the right seat but not acting as PIC count as a passenger? The regs don't seem so clear in this matter. It's always good to have a safety pilot if you haven't done something in a while, especially at night.

Comment: You mention "Safety Pilot", are you specifically talking IFR currency? You mention day/night which makes me think VFR, but typically you don't use safety pilots for VFR operations.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm just using the term safety pilot generically - a second set of eyes to keep you from making an oops at night. Always good to have two people looking at the altimeter and airspeed on final at night, especially if one were out of practice :-)

Comment: [Safety Pilots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_pilot) are usually there to maintain visual separation with traffic, weather, and terrain, and can log time either as PIC or SIC for IFR currency. If you just have a pilot rated friend tag along for some extra eyes, they are a passenger, unless they are acting as PIC. See the answer I linked (and the Wikipedia article) for more info.

Comment: How should I deal with this question if I find the link you sent satisfactory?

Comment: Its not negatively impacting your reputation, so you can leave it and let it drop off, that will make it better for somebody else who comes along and searches for wording similar to yours.